# Mean value for a specific level of a variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset and I just want the mean of the column 'Price' for the 'Category' = 'Italian'

```
df.head()
Price   Category
10.5    Italian
32.4    Filipino
56.8    Sushi
8.45    Italian

meanprice = df.groupby('Category').mean()
```

and then I found no way to do a simple

```
meanita= df.loc['Category' == 'Italian']
```

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: the mean value for the category italian, that is  10.5 + 8.45 / 2, ie 9.47

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df.loc[df['Category'] == 'Italian', 'Price'].mean()
# 9.475
```